# Citizenship name order

Tags: adjectives, word-order, names, compound-adjectives

If I'm a dual citizenship holder, which one comes first? Is there an ordering to it?

For example, if I receive a Canadian citizenship and I hold an Italian citizenship, am I Italian-Canadian or Canadian-Italian?

Comment: There is no rule **of English language** about it. It may be quite important how one states one's citizenships, if one has more than one, in a document that has legal implications, but that is a matter of country-specific legal rules, and so outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if I receive a Canadian citizenship and I hold an Italian citizenship, am I Italian-Canadian or Canadian-Italian?

Either, or neither; those terms don't actually refer to citizenship.

The term "Italian Canadians" refers to Canadians who are "Italian" in some way, normally that they have some Italian heritage. For example, if you were born and raised in Canada, but one of your parents immigrated from Italy, then you and that parent may well identify as Italian Canadians.

The term "Canadian Italians" is less common [[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Italian+Canadians%2C+Canadian+Italians&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CItalian%20Canadians%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CCanadian%20Italians%3B%2Cc0)]; it refers to Italians who are "Canadian" in some way, but does *not* normally mean that they have Canadian heritage, I think because immigration to Italy from Canada has never been as common as the reverse. (And perhaps also because Italian Canadians are more likely to be mentioned in English-language sources, what with Canada being a predominantly English-speaking country.) Rather, "Canadian Italians" most often refers to Italians living in Canada, and in that sense it heavily overlaps with "Italian Canadians", the distinction being in whether we consider someone mainly Canadian or mainly Italian. You can see this sort of usage at http://plainshumanities.unl.edu/encyclopedia/doc/egp.ea.021, which uses the term "Italians" to refer to Italian immigrants to the U.S. and Canada, and "Canadian Italians" to specifically distinguish the ones who immigrated to Canada as opposed to the U.S.

So to bring this back to your question . . . if someone thinks of you as mainly Canadian (but wants to mention your Italian background), then they'll probably call you Italian-Canadian, and if they think of you as mainly Italian, then they'll probably call you an Italian.